# get date from datetime field Mysql query

Tags: c#, asp.net, mysql, datetime

I want to fetch date from a datetime field, when i select this field in database i get the result as **'yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss'** i want the result to be like **dd/mm/yyyy**

I am developing website using ASP.net C# using Mysql.query i have made is:

//*********to get next date

> string nextdatequery = "SELECT next_dt
>   FROM testcase.heardt where fil_no=?
>   and next_dt>?;";

Please Help me sort my issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

instead of `next_dt` use `convert(nvarchar(255),next_dt,103)`

```
SELECT convert(nvarchar(255),next_dt,103) FROM testcase.heardt where fil_no=? and next_dt>?;
```

[date time styles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx)

**UPD**: I'm really sorry, i don't noticed that question is about MySql and wrote tsql code above. For MySql try something like this:

```
DATE_FORMAT(next_dt,'%d/%m/%Y')
```

Comment: I get the following error when i execute the your command: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(255),next_dt,103) FROM testcase.heardt where fil_no='04031028132001'' at line 1

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT convert(nvarchar(255), 'next_dt', 103) FROM testcase.heardt where fil_no=? and next_dt>?;
```

see below link

http://www.sqlusa.com/bestpractices/datetimeconversion/

Comment: I get the following error when i execute the your command: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(255),'next_dt',103) FROM testcase.heardt where fil_no='04031028132001'' at line 1